# tail output of program

Tags: bash, tail

How do you use tail to get the last line outputted by a program. I've tried the following so far:

```
echo `cmd` >> stdin && tail -1 stdin
```

For instance:

```
henry@henry-pc:~$ echo "abc\n123" >> stdin && tail -1 stdin
abc\n123
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to specify `stdout` as the output as it is natural. You would want to use a pipe char to pipe the output (stdout) to the `tail` utility.

You would want do to something like:

`printf 'abc\n123\n' | tail -1`

This will print `123`.

Answer (score 0):

`your command` | `tail -n`

here n implies number of lines the user needs to be tailed.

so for your need,

`your command` | `tail -1`